# Finitely many singular points of an irreducible polynomial

Tags: algebraic-geometry

let $k$ be a field, and consider an irreducible polynomial $f∈k[x,y]$. Let $S(f)$ denote the singular points of $f$ (points that are simultaneously zero on $f$, the $x$-derivative of $f$, and the $y$-derivative of $f$.)

If $k$ is algebraically closed, How can I prove that $S(f)$ is finite?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: The locus of singular points is a closed subset of the curve and is not the whole curve, hence it is finite.

Answer (score 17):

The singularities of the curve $V(f)$ form the closed set $S(f)=V(f,\partial f/\partial x, \partial f/\partial y)\subset V(f)$  . 
Closedness of $S(f)$ is obvious but finiteness is not, contrary  to what you often read on this site and elsewhere.

The basic (non-trivial!) result  is that two affine plane curves $V(f),V(g)\subset \mathbb A^2(k)$ intersect in finitely many points if $f,g$ have no common irreducible factor.
So in our case, since $f$ is irreducible, it suffices to prove that for example $f$ does not divide one of $\partial f/\partial x, \partial f/\partial y$,  which looks pretty obvious for reasons of degree.
 End of story? No, because $\partial f/\partial x$ (for example)  might be zero if $char. k=p$ !
For example $f=x^py+1$ is irreducible but nevertheless satisfies $\partial f/\partial x=0$ in characteristic $p$.
However we are saved because $\partial f/\partial y=x^p\neq 0$
This will always be the case: an irreducible polynomial $f(x,y)$  with $\partial f/\partial x=\partial f/\partial y=0$ is a  polynomial $f(x,y)=\phi(x^p,y^p)$ in $x^p,y^p$ and thus over an algebraically closed field is  a $p$-th power $f(x,y)=\phi(x^p,y^p)=\psi(x,y)^p$  and so is not  irreducible.
Contrapositively, if $f$ is irreducible then it is guaranteed to not divide at least one of $\partial f/\partial x,\partial f/\partial y$ and so, indeed, $S(f)=V(f,\partial f/\partial x, \partial f/\partial y)\subset V(f)$ is a finite (maybe empty) set.

**Conclusion**
Yes, an irreducible plane curve has only finitely many singularities but you have to work to prove it!

Comment: +1 for saying the finiteness is not as obvious as people seem to enjoy claiming. Also note that we don't require the field to be algebraically closed. [Here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09GZ) is the Stacks reference. Also, for the benefit of students I'll leave [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/793113/14657) to a proof that two affine plane curves intersect in finitely many points if $f$ and $g$ have no common factor.

Comment: Thanks for your interest and the reference, @Ragib.

Comment: Why is $f$ a p-power?

Comment: @Zero If there is some power of $x$ or $y$ which is not a multiple of $p$, then the derivative will be nonzero, for example $(d/dx) (x^{p-1}) = (p - 1)x^{p - 2} \neq 0$.